# May I use Koush/ion in a commercial Project?

Tags: android, licensing, android-ion, ion-koush

I try to figure out if I am allowed to use the koush/ion lib in a commercial project and if using is for free (I am only using the "imageload to list view"-part)? Does any one know about this issue?
In order to avoid missunderstandings.....I don't want to use the work from others without mentioning these of cause.
I hope for help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's released under Apache 2.0 so as long as you attribute, what;'s the problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use it on a commercial project since it's granted the APACHE 2.0 license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0), as stated here: [https://github.com/koush/ion/blob/master/LICENSE](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)